# how to create .mpd mpeg dash File from mp4 video

Tags: video, exoplayer, mpeg-dash

I am developing a video player app. where my requirement is run video on different resolutions. I am new video app. i searched and found mpeg dash file contents different resolutions with manifest. Can any help me that how can i create mpeg dash file manifest from mp4 high resolution video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several fairly well supported ways you can do this - two of he most common (outside of dedicated packager software solutions):

**ffmpeg**

The documentation online includes the following example:

```js
ffmpeg -re -i <input> -map 0 -map 0 -c:a libfdk_aac -c:v libx264 \
-b:v:0 800k -b:v:1 300k -s:v:1 320x170 -profile:v:1 baseline \
-profile:v:0 main -bf 1 -keyint_min 120 -g 120 -sc_threshold 0 \
-b_strategy 0 -ar:a:1 22050 -use_timeline 1 -use_template 1 \
-window_size 5 -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v id=1,streams=a" \
-f dash /path/to/out.mpd
```

from: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#dash-2

**MP4Box**

Again the documentation is online and includes some example:

> MP4Box -dash 10000 -frag 1000 -rap -segment-name myDash
> -subsegs-per-sidx 5 -url-template test.mp4

from: https://gpac.wp.imt.fr/2012/02/01/dash-support/

Comment: i am getting "at least one output file must specified" in ffmpeg .

ffmpeg -re -i demo.mp4 -map 0 -map 0 -c:a libfdk_aac -c:v libx26 -b:v:0 800k -b:v:1 300k -s:v:1 320x170 -profile:v:1 baseline -profile:v:0 main -bf 1 -keyint_min 120 -sc_threshold 0 -b_strategy 0 -ar:a:1 22050 -use_timeline 1 -use_template 1 -window_size 5 -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v id=1,streams=a" -f dash/to/out.mpd

Comment: @DevMobApp - are you replacing the "dash/to/out.mpd" with whatever output file you want? Also, take a look here, especially if using windows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42249107/334402